# JsonArray and JsonObject

Tags: android

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"58",
         "parent_id":"0",
         "cat_name":"Cricket",
         "cat_img":"physical",
         "cat_status":"1",
         "child_category":[  
            {  
               "id":"68",
               "parent_id":"58",
               "cat_name":"Matches",
               "cat_img":"physical",
               "cat_status":"1"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

how to parse this type of JSON in android and show in the expandable list as the child-parent relationship

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Google's [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse and use Json objects in Android.

An example for parsing:

```
private static class MyJsonModel {
   Data data[];
}

private static class Data {
   int id;
   int parent_id;
   String cat_name;
   ...
}

MyJsonModel parseMyJsonString(String jsonString) {
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
   return (MyJsonModel)(gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyJsonModel.class));
}
```